# "max_pool2d in module tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.arg_scope:" Where can I find the code of max_pool2d?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

```
import tensorflow as tf
slim = tf.contrib.slim
slim.max_pool2d(inputs,[1,1],stride=factor,scope=scope)
```

**I want to see the internal code of max_pool2d. Where could I find it ?**

Answer (score 0):

[`layers.py:2097`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L2097):

```
@add_arg_scope
def max_pool2d(inputs,
               kernel_size,
               stride=2,
               padding='VALID',
               data_format=DATA_FORMAT_NHWC,
               outputs_collections=None,
               scope=None):
  """Adds a 2D Max Pooling op.

  It is assumed that the pooling is done per image but not in batch or channels.

  Args:
    inputs: A 4-D tensor of shape `[batch_size, height, width, channels]` if
      `data_format` is `NHWC`, and `[batch_size, channels, height, width]` if
      `data_format` is `NCHW`.
    kernel_size: A list of length 2: [kernel_height, kernel_width] of the
      pooling kernel over which the op is computed. Can be an int if both
      values are the same.
    stride: A list of length 2: [stride_height, stride_width].
      Can be an int if both strides are the same. Note that presently
      both strides must have the same value.
    padding: The padding method, either 'VALID' or 'SAME'.
    data_format: A string. `NHWC` (default) and `NCHW` are supported.
    outputs_collections: The collections to which the outputs are added.
    scope: Optional scope for name_scope.

  Returns:
    A `Tensor` representing the results of the pooling operation.

  Raises:
    ValueError: If `data_format` is neither `NHWC` nor `NCHW`.
    ValueError: If 'kernel_size' is not a 2-D list
  """
  if data_format not in (DATA_FORMAT_NCHW, DATA_FORMAT_NHWC):
    raise ValueError('data_format has to be either NCHW or NHWC.')
  with ops.name_scope(scope, 'MaxPool2D', [inputs]) as sc:
    inputs = ops.convert_to_tensor(inputs)
    df = ('channels_first' if data_format and data_format.startswith('NC')
          else 'channels_last')
    layer = pooling_layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=kernel_size,
                                        strides=stride,
                                        padding=padding,
                                        data_format=df,
                                        _scope=sc)
    outputs = layer.apply(inputs)
    return utils.collect_named_outputs(outputs_collections, sc, outputs)
```

Comment: In fact, I find the codes in Github. But Thank you for your kind answer.